# Laravel Passport: rewrite client middleware for check access token from custom header name insted of Authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

Laravel Passport `Client Credentials Grant Tokens` can be protected with their middleware

**Client middleware**

`\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials;`

This middleware will check user credential from `Authorization` header field. How I can change it and for checking from custom header name? For example: `clientAuthorization`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom middleware, extend it from `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials` middleware in your Laravel application and re-write the method to use your custom header (`clientAuthorization`).

Then use the custom middleware in your application.

Comment: I could't found where in this laravel passport middlewere difined header with name `Authorization` for check. @Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim